# Why was I able to git push yesterday, but today I get "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."?

Tags: git, github

I have been working on this same project for weeks, and haven't reconfigured anything. So why was I able to git pull, git push, etc for all these weeks and now today all of the sudden I can no longer git push.
I get the error

```
$ git push origin
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just experienced the same issue. I could push/pull 30 minutes ago, I didnt change anything, now I can't
Update: for me it works again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just experienced same issue. I've turned WiFi on/off and problem fixed. You could give it a try.

Comment: @mastercool If the problem was temporary and is now solved, please delete the question.